# Cant connect to Phoenix using JDBC in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-phoenix

I have a spring-boot application where I am trying to configure phoenix DataSource but getting "no suitable Driver" found error.

```
@Bean(name="phoenixDataSource")
@DependsOn(value = "placeholderConfigurer")
public DataSource phoenixDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource phoenixDataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        phoenixDataSource.setUrl( "jdbc:phoenix:localhost" );
        try {
            Class<?> driverClass = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
            phoenixDataSource.setDriverClass((Class<? extends Driver>) driverClass);
        } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       );
        return phoenixDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "phoenixJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate phoenixJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("phoenixDataSource") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Like: please add the stack trace, at least the relevant parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step you need to find wether you have access to connect or not
Connect to sqline using /usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/bin/sqlline.py

```
 /usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/bin/sqlline.py <Zoo-keeper-url>:2181:/hbase-unsecure
```

If  your Habse is not set unsecure so you need to find wether its Kerberos or HBase protected by Ranger authorization ,you can find required information in your logs.

**Now you have  following three options to connect**

- Zookeper URL with non secure

  ```
    "jdbc:phoenix:<Zookeeper_host_name> :<port_number> : /hbase-unsecure"); //With No password
  ```
- Zookeper URL with  secure

  ```
    "jdbc:phoenix:<Zookeeper_host_name>:<port_number>:<secured_Zookeeper_node>:<user_name> "
  ```
- With URL

  ```
     jdbc:phoenix:thin:url=<scheme>://<server-hostname>:<port>;authentication=vaquarkhan
  ```

Default zookeeper port =2181.

following code you can use for setup connection make sure you already added dependancy into POM file

POM :

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_05</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0-HBase-1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sqlline</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlline</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

JavaCode:

```
package com.khan.vaquar.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

/**
 * Database Configures for Phoenix database.
 */

@Configuration
public class DBConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new SimpleDriverDataSource(new org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver(),
                "jdbc:phoenix:<Zookeeper-URL> :<PORT_NO> : /hbase-unsecure"); 
                

    }

@Bean
   public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate databasePhoenixJdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource());
        template.setQueryTimeout("1500");
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(template);
   }
    
}
```

Inside your repo use it for connection

```
 @Autowired
 private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate databasePhoenixJdbcTemplate;
```

Few useful links :

- https://phoenix.apache.org/server.html
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-pass-user-with-Phoenix-url/td-p/96707
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Phoenix-JDBC-Client-Setup/ta-p/244284
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/SQuirreL-on-phoenix-Sandbox/m-p/153362
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Phoenix-Part-4-working-with-Ranger/ta-p/249174

Answer (score 0):

There is two kind of drivers Thin and Thick.

Your code is using the thick driver.
so, you have to add the phoenix-core jar file to your classpath.

I'm using hdp 3.0.1.0-187 phoenix server.

In my gradle configuration is below.

implementation('org.apache.phoenix:phoenix-core:5.0.0-HBase-2.0')